# How to work with a pdf form in Langchain?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, py-langchain

I have a pdf file that is questionnaire. There is text that cannot be changed which are the questions and then text boxes with the answers. When I run this simple code:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

loader = PyPDFLoader("files/blo-file.pdf")
pages = loader.load_and_split()
pages
```

It doesn't include any of the information that was filled out. It only has the questions. How can I also get the answers to the questions? Thanks.

Comment: Hey just wanted to see if you found a solution to this. I'm also dealing with the same problem

Comment: No I have not --